# How refresh Flickity plugin?

Tags: plugins, slider, window, refresh, flickity

I have a problem with Flickity plugin. I want to use this one mixed with svgLoader plugin. The slider animation does't work correctly because you need to resize the window for refresh flickity plugin.
You can try it here : http://thibaut-lalanne.com/
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually refresh the slider anytime.

```
yourFlickitySlider.resize();
```

Answer (score 4):

Resize the carousel and re-position cells like so:

```
// jQuery
var $carousel = $('.carousel').flickity()
$carousel.flickity('resize')

// vanilla JS
var flkty = new Flickity('.carousel');
flkty.resize()
```

For examples see: https://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html#resize